# Trapping dot (.) file not found errors in KSH

Tags: ksh

In ksh88, I can source a file using the "dot" command, like

```
. /my/file/source.ksh
```

However, if source.ksh doesn't exist, I want to trap the error.

So I tried this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

trap "echo 'Source Not Found'; exit 1" ERR
. test2.ksh
```

But the trap never displays the error message, the script returns with:

```
./test.ksh[4]: test2.ksh:  not found.
```

I even tried just using `trap` without any signals and it still doesn't catch the error.

Is there any way to catch this error? I must use ksh88 for this script. Bash answers are useless for this question.

I am aware that I can test for the existence of the file beforehand, I was just hoping there would be a way to trap this error without having to do that, as there are a bunch of these includes in my script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `command` command to remove the *special* behavior (whereby failure causes the shell to exit among other things) of *special builtins* in POSIX shells like `ksh` or `bash`.

So:

```
if ! command . /my/file/source.ksh; then
  echo >&2 ". failed"
  exit 1
fi
```

Now, `.` may fail if `/my/file/source.ksh` can't be found, or can't be open for reading, or there's an error reading it or parsing it, or the last command run within it returns failure.

If you only want to consider the case where `source.ksh` can't be open for reading, you can use `exec` (another *special builtin*):

```
die() {
  IFS=" "
  printf >&2 'Error: %s\n' "$*"
  exit 1
}
command exec 3< /my/file/source.ksh || die "Can't read the file"
command . /dev/fd/3
```

Or use `eval` instead of `.`:

```
code=$(cat /my/file/source.ksh) || die "Can't read the file"
eval "$code"
```

Comment: Thanks! I really want the case where it fails for any reason - the files just contain function definitions. I'll try out the `command` command and see how it goes.